# How can I load images from database using Livebinds?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, livebindings

I downloaded images from a webservice, saved then into a TBitmap and used the command: `bmpExample.SaveToStream(stExample);` and saved the stream into my database (SQLite) PS: the column is a Blob field.

Until here everything works fine! I can see the image on the Data tab, the problem start when I try to load the image back to my application (firemonkey). I'm using the livebinds tool and linked my ListView into my Query (`select * from empresa`) in this way:

[image]

The header and the text loads fine, the only problem is with the image (that I know that exist because I can see on the Data tab of my SQL editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, was because I used `qMyQuery.Open` after download the company informations, and after I had the ID of the company, I downloaded and inserted the images on the database but I did not said to my query to access again the database.

The answer to my problem:

```
Dm.qMyQuery.Close;
Dm.qMyQuery.Open();
```